# Custom Jekyll Plugin (Liquid Filter?) rendering script tags as text, not as JavaScript

Tags: ruby, schema, jekyll, liquid

I'm experimenting with building a site using Jekyll for a friend.

I'm trying to transform front matter from files like `/_events/2020-02-25-an-event.md` and `/_events/2020-02-26-another-event.md` into something that can be easily embedded into the body of various building blocks of content and result in those pages, as viewed by a visitor, including `<script type="application/ld+json">...</script>` tags conforming to [schema.org event](https://schema.org/Event) standards.

A file like `/_events/2020-02-25-an-event.md` looks like this:

```
---
layout: event
title: An event
published: true
startdatetime: 2020-02-28
venue: Best Club Ever
---
```

Members of the `events` collection are meant to render as individual viewable URLs and should have a snippet of JavaScript hiding in their rendered output like this:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    [
        {
            "@context" : "http://schema.org",
            "@type" : "Event",
            "name" : "An event",
            "startDate" : "2020-02-28",
            "location" : "Best Club Ever blah blah ... have address stuff to work out, still"
        }
    ]
</script>
```

I got that working by writing `/_plugins/event_schema.rb` as follows:

```
require 'liquid'

module EventSchemaFilters

  def do_not_use_me_directly_single_json_curly(input_object)
    %Q(
        {
            "@context" : "http://schema.org",
            "@type" : "Event",
            "name" : "#{input_object['title']}",
            "startDate" : "#{input_object['startdatetime']}",
            "location" : "#{input_object['venue']}"
        }
    )
  end

  def event_single_schema_script(input_object)
    %Q(
        <script type="application/ld+json">
        [
            #{do_not_use_me_directly_single_json_curly(input_object)}
        ]
        </script>
    )
  end

  def event_multiple_schema_script(input_object_array)
    %Q(
        <script type="application/ld+json">
        [
            #{input_object_array.map(&method(:do_not_use_me_directly_single_json_curly)).join(',')}
        ]
        </script>
    )
  end

  def event_multiple_schema_script(input_object_array)
    %Q(
        <script type="application/ld+json">
        [
            #{input_object_array.map(&method(:do_not_use_me_directly_single_json_curly)).join(',')}
        ]
        </script>
    )
  end

  end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(EventSchemaFilters)
```

And then by writing `/_layouts/event.html` *(which looks up to "page" layout, which looks up to "default" layout)* as:

```
---
layout: page
---

{{ page | event_single_schema_script }}
```

Unfortunately, if I write `/index.md` like this, while I get a nice little array of upcoming events, it renders surrounded by `<code>`...`</code>` tags and shows up in the body of the home page:

```
---
title: Home Page
layout: default
---

# {{ page.title }}

{{ site.events | event_multiple_schema_script }}
```

The desire is to have this script be part of the DOM's JavaScript ... not part of the text on the page:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    [
        {
            "@context" : "http://schema.org",
            "@type" : "Event",
            "name" : "An event",
            "startDate" : "2020-02-28",
            "location" : "Best Club Ever blah blah ... have address stuff to work out, still"
        }
        ,
        {
            "@context" : "http://schema.org",
            "@type" : "Event",
            "name" : "Another event",
            "startDate" : "2020-02-27",
            "location" : "Less Good Club blah blah ... have address stuff to work out, still"
        }
    ]
</script>
```

Moving `{{ site.events | event_multiple_schema_script }}` to be the contents of `/_includes/event_all_schema_script.html` and trying `{% include event_all_schema_script.html %}` didn't help at all -- same problem.

Removing the call to `{% include event_all_schema_script.html %}` from `/index.md` and putting it into `/_layouts/default.html` instead *does* render the way I want it to.  But now it's on every page, including pages like `https://example.com/events/2020-02-25-an-event/`, which is not what I want.  But it does demonstrate that my problem is that I wrote something I can't just "inject" into the markdown of a ... thing ... that's going to become a web page.

Things that also work in `/index.md` but aren't what I want to do:

- Hand-writing `<script>...</script>` code straight into it
- Putting `{% include event_all_schema_script_hardcode.html %}` into it, where `/_includes/event_all_schema_script_hardcode.html` is literally just `<script>...</script>` text copy-pasted from the output I showed all of you.

  - If only "generators for dummies" material weren't so hard to find *(Jekyll documentation isn't very extensive; Google is useless because the phrase "static site generator" is to prevalent)*, maybe I could write code that would make building such a file at build-time possible?  This seems like a pretty high bar to get over, though., with my current Jekyll/Ruby knowledge.

I'm open to re-architecting this, by the way.  Not attached to the idea of "filtering" things like `site.events`, etc.  This is just as far as I got in my "hello world."

The only principles I'm really attached to in a final design:

- All data entry into the calendar of "events" should be done through the front matter of items in the `events` collection *(so I can get a CMS like Forestry.io or Netlify CMS to play nice with it)*.
- The computation of the contents of the `<script>...</script>` block should happen in an "independent, insertable component."

  - I don't want to do a big Liquid loop inside `/_layouts/homepage.html` that I have to remind a web designer to copy/paste into `/_layouts/better_homepage.html`.
  - Instead, I just want to be able to tell a web designer, "Hey, if you want to make a page's metadata include a feed of events, just drop `{% include event_all_schema_script.html %}` somewhere into it or its layout."
  - I want `{% include event_all_schema_script.html %}`, or whatever equivalent people here help me come up with, to work both in the body of pages/posts/collection-markdown and in layouts.
- I'm going to take what I learn from this to also write "plain-old DIVs for web designers to style as they see fit" like `/_includes/event_all_div.html` and `/_includes/event_single_div.html`, and to let them be used anywhere that the web designer sees fit -- in markdown or in a layout.

  - Again, I'm not a web designer.  I'm just the data-structure transformation person.  My only goal is to generate nice, "boring" snippets of HTML that are ready for a proper web designer to reuse and style as they see fit.

Any thoughts on how I can improve this attempt at rendering HTML so it will be both layout- and markdown-friendly?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Workaround w/ `/_includes/evnt.json` as `{"@context" : "http://schema.org", "@type" : "Event", "name" : "{{ include.event_name }}"}`, `/_includes/all_evts_script.html` as `<script type="application/ld+json">[{% for evt in site.events %}{% include evnt.json event_name=evt.title %}{% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}{% endfor %}]</script>`, & `/_includes/single_evt_page_script.html` as `{% if page.collection == 'events' %}<script type="application/ld+json">[{% include evnt.json event_name=page.title %}]</script>{% endif %}`, but still ?? why a function call renders badly in Markdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem but it certainly comes from the fact that Kramdown understands any line with four spaces indentation or more like a [standard code block](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#standard-code-blocks).

If you don't want to process some parts of your markdown files, you can use [`nomarkdown` extension](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#extensions) like this :

```
{::nomarkdown}  
     Any indented line or block
{:/nomarkdown}
```

Another workaround can be to switch to html files for your events.

Comment: Oh, wow, that _(the indentation thing)_ makes so much sense!  Can .HTML files have front matter just like .MD files?  The idea is to use the front matter of the "event" files like values for records in a database _(planning to use Netlify CMS or Forestry.io to let a non-technical person add events to the calendar)_.

Comment: Also, I got so frustrated with this effort yesterday that I ended up using a simple parameterized-include structure and deleted all the code that I wrote.  So I have to find some time to rebuild it all to test whether your suggestion works.  Sorry I can't mark answer as "accepted" right away -- hope to get to that over the weekend!

Comment: If you don't need to add structured content (bellow front matter) to you collection items, just go `.html` extension, this will avoid the indentation glitch with markdown. Otherwise, if you have to include markdown content from netlify cms, you can go with the `nomarkdown` around your plugin code, it will work well.