# kramdown (Jekyll): How do I indent entire paragraph without converting it to codeblock

Tags: jekyll, indentation, kramdown

Is there a built-in syntax for indenting an entire paragraph in kramdown. Adding four spaces (or tab) at the start of a paragraph just converts in to codeblock, and I can't find any solution after some searching.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60451213/1548376

Comment: @David Jacquel. Thanks. I solved it by writing a short snippet and adding it to `_includes`, but the suggestion in the answer you posted looks more like what I was looking for, something that doesn't require any include file.

Comment: The suggestion in that link doesn't work unfortunately. Leading spaces are ignored.